# Why Doesn't This URL Work in IXMLHttpRequest Object?

Tags: vbscript, yahoo, google-finance

I built some code to retrieve stock data from Yahoo as a CSV file, and it works fine. When I change the URL to the *perfectly legal* version that recalls minutewise data from Google instead, it fails on the

```
objHTTP.open "GET", strURL, False
```

statement.

The following code shows both URLs, although obviously only the final one is called. Both URLs work when posted into the address bar of a browser.

Can anyone explain why the call to Google's page won't Open?

```
  option explicit

   Dim objHTTP
   dim strURL
   dim objFile

   dim objFSO
   Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
   ' WORKS:
   strURL = "http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=UPRO&a=04&b=21&c=2016&d=04&e=31&f=2016&g=d&ignore=.csv"
   ' DOES NOT WORK:
   strURL = "www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=UPRO&i=60&p=20d&f=d,c,v,k,o,h,l&df=cpct&auto=0&ei=Ef6XUYDfCqSTiAKEMg"

   objHTTP.open "GET", strURL, False
   objHTTP.send
   msgbox objHTTP.responseText 
   Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile _
      ("Yahoo.csv", 2)
   objFile.Write objHTTP.ResponseText
   objFile.Close
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `http://` from the broken URL. When I added this, I got response data.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer, may be try padding out the answer a bit? The reason it works is because the [IXMLHttpRequest object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757849(v=vs.85).aspx) expects a valid URL *(which means including the protocol `http` or `https` for example)*. From the docs - *"The requested URL. This can be either an absolute URL, such as `"http://Myserver/Mypath/Myfile.asp"`, or a relative URL, such as `"../MyPath/MyFile.asp"`."*